# Load a web page into a headless Jasmine spec running PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, jsdom, headless-browser

How do I read in a page from `localhost` into a headless Jasmine spec so test cases can work on the DOM elements?

My Gulp task is successfully running Jasmine specs for unit testing, and now I need to build integration tests to verify full web pages served from `localhost`.  I'm using the [`gulp-jasmine-browser`](https://github.com/jasmine/gulp-jasmine-browser) plugin to run PhantomJS.

Example:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp =           require('gulp');
var jasmineBrowser = require('gulp-jasmine-browser');

function specRunner() {
   gulp.src(['node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'src/js/*.js', 'spec/*.js'])
      .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({ console: true }))
      .pipe(jasmineBrowser.headless());
   }

gulp.task('spec', specRunner);
```

**spec/cart-spec.js**

```
describe('Cart component', function() {

   it('displays on the gateway page', function() {
      var page = loadWebPage('http://localhost/');  //DOES NOT WORK
      var cart = page.find('#cart');
      expect(cart.length).toBe(1);
      });

   });
```

There is no `loadWebPage()` function.  It's just to illustrate the functionality I believe is needed.

Comment: Are you looking for PhantomJS's [page.open](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) method?

Comment: If what you are doing is trying to use Jasmine to navigate around and follow links, you might want to think about moving to a secondary framework, like Zombie and/or Selenium.

Comment: @Gerrit0 Yeah, I've seen `page.open` and it does the right thing, but it's a PhantomJS module with no obvious way to call it from a Jasmine spec.  If you know how, please tell.

Comment: @Bob_Gneu Selenium requires Java, so it's definitely out.  PhantomJS is generally considered to be able to do everything Zombie.js can do (but the browser emulation in Zombie.js is supposed to be faster than the headless WebKit in PhantomJS).

Comment: http://webdriver.io is a selenium driver for node. Pretty sure you don't need to bother with any Java code for this to be used.

Comment: Because of the jasmine dependency on the browser to execute this is going to be tough. I typically use mocha and zombie when I'm diving into automated integration testing. That way I only have to start up the server and navigate around. Doing it in a contest where the tests are already run in the browser is not going to work well. One saving grace is that jasmine tests can be run via the cli. That might give you some latitude to load external libraries and get phantoms to work as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## jsdom to the rescue!

It turns out it's pretty easy to load a web page into a headless Jasmine spec... but you need to swap out PhantomJS for [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Strategy:

1. Use Jasmine's `beforeAll()` to call a function that will run `JSDOM.fromURL()` to request the web page.
2. Once the web page has been loaded into the DOM, expose `window` and `jQuery` for use in your test cases.
3. Finally, call `done()` to indicate the tests are now ready to run.

Make sure to close the `window` after the tests have run.

### spec.js

```js
const url  = 'http://dnajs.org/';
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
let window, $;
function loadWebPage(done) {
   function handleWebPage(dom) {
      function waitForScripts() {
         window = dom.window;
         $ = dom.window.jQuery;
         done();
         }
      dom.window.onload = waitForScripts;
      }
   const options = { resources: 'usable', runScripts: 'dangerously' };
   JSDOM.fromURL(url, options).then(handleWebPage);
   }
function closeWebPage() { window.close(); }

describe('The web page', () => {

   beforeAll(loadWebPage);
   afterAll(closeWebPage);

   it('has the correct URL', () => {
      expect(window.location.href).toBe(url);
      });

   it('has exactly one header, main, and footer', () => {
      const actual =   {
          header: $('body >header').length,
          main:   $('body >main').length,
          footer: $('body >footer').length
          };
      const expected = { header: 1, main: 1, footer: 1 };
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
      });

   });
```

### Test output

[image: screenshot]
*Note:* Above screenshot is from a similar Mocha spec since Mocha has a nice default reporter.

### Project

It's on GitHub if you want try it out yourself:
https://github.com/dnajs/load-web-page-jsdom-jasmine

*EDITED:* Updated for jsdom 11

Comment: If Mocha is more your flavor, check out: https://github.com/dnajs/load-web-page-jsdom-mocha

Answer (score 3):

End-to-End testing frameworks like a [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/), [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/), [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) and so on are more suitable in such case.

The `gulp-jasmine-browser` plugin still is about the Unit testing in the browser environment. It is not possible to navigate between pages.

Comment: I'm not trying to navigate between pages.

Comment: You need to load and verify full web pages served from localhost. It is an e2e testing. Page loading is a navigation. Just use an appropriate tools.

Answer (score 2):

I put together the following code that appears to work. Please feel free to check out [my repo](https://bitbucket.org/Bob_Gneu/so-40779032) and confirm in your own environment.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "40646680",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp jasmine"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-jasmine-browser": "^1.7.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7"
  }
}
```

#### gulpfile.js

```
(() => {
    "use strict";

    var gulp = require("gulp"),
        jasmineBrowser = require("gulp-jasmine-browser");

    gulp.task("jasmine", () => {
        return gulp.src("test/*.js")
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({
                console: true
            }))
            .pipe(jasmineBrowser.headless());
    });
})();
```

#### test/sampleJasmine.js

```
describe("A suite", function() {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
    it("contains failing spec with an expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

#### Execution

```
Bob Chatman@CHATBAG42 F:\Development\StackOverflow\40646680
> npm test

> 40646680@1.0.0 test F:\Development\StackOverflow\40646680
> gulp jasmine

[21:56:44] Using gulpfile F:\Development\StackOverflow\40646680\gulpfile.js
[21:56:44] Starting 'jasmine'...
[21:56:44] Jasmine server listening on port 8000
.F
Failures:
1) A suite contains failing spec with an expectation
1.1) Expected true to be false.

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0 seconds
[21:56:49] 'jasmine' errored after 4.26 s
[21:56:49] Error in plugin 'gulp-jasmine-browser'
Message:
    1 failure
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

#### Dependencies

```
node 7.2
npm 3.9.3
jasmine 2.5.2
phantomjs 2.1.7 
gulp 3.9.1
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to how this solution answers the question?

Comment: As our discussion above has evolved, I don't think it addresses the later aspect. Please disregard this. I may look into it later this weekend if I get a chance and make it more accurately address the integration aspect.